# how to see changes on mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I need to see changes that are made by users on database. I see the all queries on the Profile Data on MMS. Do I need to eliminate the queries that changes the database myself or is there a defined way in the mongodb?

Comment: How are your users accessing the database? Via the console/db-app or via an application?

Comment: I haven't constructed the system yet. I am making test on the mongodb.

Comment: What information are you trying to see, exactly? Do you want to log all queries and/or updates to your MongoDB instance or are you trying to see a subset of activity? MongoDB [profile data](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/) is saved to a capped collection which means you will only see a snapshot of recent activity. Rather than exporting this information to MMS you would be better viewing it on your MongoDB server directly. Sending all profile or log data to MMS could use some significant (and unnecessary) bandwidth.

Comment: Thank you, I have solved the problem logging setting profile level to 2. But now, I can't find the backup history list which shows the exact time of the backup. I have searched but I have found almost nothing.

Comment: @user2931957: Which backup history list are you referring to? MMS Backup?

Comment: No. Backup which are taken by mongodump without using MMS Backup.

Comment: @user2931957: Just noticed your last comment here (!). If you are taking backups with `mongodump` you'll have to log the history for this yourself (perhaps by wrapping in a bash script which appends the date of last successful backup after mongodump completes). Note: if you have a replica set you should use the `mongodump --oplog` option to get an approximate point-in-time backup.